# Почему унарный плюс не меняет знак числа?

Tags: javascript

В отличие от унарного плюса, унарный минус меняет знак числа. Например:

```
let a = 3; 
a = -a; 
console.log(a);//--> -3
```

Унарный плюс почему-то этого не может.

```
let a = -3; 
a = +a; 
console.log(a);//--> -3
```

Получается,что единственное, что может делать унарный плюс - это преобразовывать операнд к числу?

Comment: А почему  знак должен меняться? Простая математика: `1 + (-1) = 0`, то же что и `1 - 1 = 0`

Comment: Почему он е меняет знак это вопрос к Эйху.. Минус - меняет знак, плюс - преобразовывает в числа. Вопрос не имеет смысла, это "константы" языка, а не работа пользовательской функции

Comment: @slippyk да, вы правы. Здесь больше вопрос к самой математике, чем к js)

Comment: К математике вопросов нет. В математике нет унарного плюса. Это всё программисты придумали 

Comment: @Alexey Ten и? В самой математике, конечно, нет такого понятия как "унарный плюс", но плюс-то есть. Вам очень важно само название?